# Assign Incrementing ID from a range

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, auto-increment

How can i go about assigning a number to a field based on what was previously selected and also only assign numbers from a range.

e.g. If i have a choice field with 3 options A, B, C

```
       A = assign unique number between (100-500)
       B = assign unique number between (501-600)
       C = assign unique number between (601-1000)
```

Is this possible to achieve with sharepoint Lists ?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: So if 2 items both have the choice filed set to be A, their ID number shall be continuous?

Comment: Only one choice at a time (Choices from A-C, sorry fixed my question above). Yes it must be unique and continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a demo based on your requirements. We can use the `Get Items` action with certain settings to get the last item with the same choice and retrieve its ID value.

[image]

The IDRange is the column which I set based on your description, its value is simply A,B,C
And the `IDRange Value` in the screenshot is a dynamic content which has the value of the string of your choice, for here is A,B or C. And `ID ne ID` is the part I use to exclude the current Item as it also has the same choice. The ID is the list item default ID.

The `IDRange` is the column IDRange's internal name, try avoid renaming column which may gives you a different internal name. Check the column internal name before setting the query.

Order By field makes all the items returned sort in order. Here I use ID desc which means all the items will be sorted by ID descending. And the top count is 1, it makes the action only return the first entry, which is the item with largest ID.

In this way we can get the last item with the same choice, then use it to update the new item.

Comment: Hi @Jerry_MSFT, how do i set this value : IDRange Value ?

Comment: @Fedora, it is a dynamic content in flow, it shall be from the current item. Have you used dynamic content before?

Comment: no i am not familiar, just came back to work. I will look videos on how it works and try this solution.